# Why are case macros not nesting?

Tags: sweet.js

Given this sweet.js macro

```
macro m {
    case { _ ( $a, $b ) } => {
        return #{$a + $b};
    }
    case { _ ( $a ) } => {
        return #{$a};
    }
    case { _ } => {
        return #{no};
    }
}

export m;
```

And this source code:

```
m(1, [m(2)]);
m(1, m(2));
```

How do you create a case that yields this output:

```
1 + [2];
1 + 2;
```

Instead of this?

```
1 + [2];
no(1, 2);
```

P.S. the actual use case requires case macros, not rule macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic thing you're running into here is that a pattern variable
only matches a single token so in `m(1, m(2))` the pattern `$b` gets
bound to `m` not `m(2)`. This is because the inner `m` macros don't
get expanded before the outer `m` macro runs.

The easiest way to fix this is to use `...`:

```
macro m {
    case { _ ( $a ..., $b ...) } => {
    return #{$a ... + $b ...};
    }
    case { _ ( $a ... ) } => {
    return #{$a ...};
    }
    case { _ } => {
    return #{no};
    }
}
```